# Unable to connect to Azure Cosmos Db Account (Core SQL API) using EF Core 3.0 CosmosDb provider

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, .net-core-3.0, entity-framework-core-3.0

I'm unable to connect to an Azure CosmosDB with the CosmosDb provider using the following packages:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos 3.0.0

Getting this message back:

Response status code does not indicate success: 503 Substatus: 0 Reason: (The request failed because the client was unable to establish connections to 3 endpoints across 1 regions. Please check for client resource starvation issues and verify connectivity between client and server.

#### Stacktrace

```
at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactory.ToObjectInternal[T](ResponseMessage cosmosResponseMessage, CosmosSerializer jsonSerializer) 
at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactory.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateDatabaseResponseAsync>b__0(ResponseMessage cosmosResponseMessage) 
at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactory.<ProcessMessageAsync>d__121.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult() at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient.<CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync>d__40.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Storage.Internal.CosmosClientWrapper.d__13.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Storage.Internal.CosmosClientWrapper.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsOnce(DbContext context, Object state) 
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementation[TState,TResult](Func3 operation, Func3 verifySucceeded, TState state) 
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func3 operation, Func3 verifySucceeded) 
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Storage.Internal.CosmosClientWrapper.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Storage.Internal.CosmosDatabaseCreator.EnsureCreated() 
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated() at EFCoreCosmosDbTest.Test.<Run>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Git\EFCoreCosmosDbTest\EFCoreCosmosDbTest\Test.cs:line 26 
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at EFCoreCosmosDbTest.Program.<Main>d__0.MoveNext()
in C:\Git\EFCoreCosmosDbTest\EFCoreCosmosDbTest\Program.cs:line 9
```

If I change to the Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core 2.8.1 and use the DocumentClient I have no issues connecting to the same CosmosDb account in Azure and create my database, container etc. from the same solution.

Also, if I download the .net core quickstart project from Azure, it works without issues.

Note, that It works fine connecting to a the Azure Cosmos Db Emulator locally with EF.

I used the https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/master/samples/core/Cosmos repo to run the test.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

- EF Core version: 3.0
- Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.CosmosDb
- Target framework: .NET Core 3.0

Comment: Have you tried updating the Cosmos SDK to 3.0.1 ?

Comment: @ErikEJ Just tried to update to 

-  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.0-preview1.19506.2"
-  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos" Version="3.1.0-preview1.19506.2"

Same issue.

Comment: I meant the Cosmos SDK, not EF Core

Comment: The Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos package - 3.0.2 is out

Comment: oh okay, but the problem is with EF core and the EF Core Cosmos Provider. I.E connecting through Their Cosmos provider. There is no issues connecting to the Azure Cosmos DB account through CosmosClient in Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos package or for example the DocumentClient in the Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB package

Answer (score 0):

The EF Provider is using the Cosmos SDK package underneath.

[image]

Please add the `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` package to your project targeting the latest version (3.2.2).

You can do this through the NET Core CLI by running `dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` on the folder with your current project files, and it should update your CSPROJ with the `PackageReference`.

Comment: Since the EF provider is using the Cosmos SDK underneath, you shouldn't be required to install it separately, right? already referenced. Anyhow it didn't make a difference installing it and still using EF to connect. Though I got an answer on this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18446 and it worked changing the `ConnectionMode` to `Gateway`

Comment: You are not required, no. But the dependency is targeting >= `3.0.0` and it might be pulling an older package version, not the latest.